# Ordered Hash Keys in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My dynamo db tables has hash key and range Key  and other data columns which we can insert .
In dynamo db what i understood is    that when items are inserted  in GSI/Base table  then items get sorted  in ascending order based on range key and hash key is not ordered.
Example  :

hashId - rangeKey

1   -    1

1   -    2

1   - 3

3   - 1

3 -     2

3   - 3

2   -1

2   -2

2   -3

Is there any way we can have a ordered hash keys as well in dynamo db?

like this when we save data in any random order :

hashId  -rangeId

1   -1

1-  2

1-  3

2    -1

2   -2

2   -3

3   -1

3-  2

3   -3

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible, because the way dynamo DB works is that it hashes the partition/hash Key and saves it in the respective partition. Though you can have sorted data in the dynamo DB based on the range key for the partition key.